# More than one bundle started with apache felix config.properties

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I've taken the example from http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2011/07/19/maven-apache-felix-easy-development-and-debugging-with-eclipse/ and I wanted to extend it adding another bundle:

```
felix.auto.deploy.action=install,start
felix.log.level=1

org.osgi.framework.storage.clean=onFirstInit

felix.auto.start.1 = \
 assembly:../test.bundle/target/classes
 assembly:../test2.bundle/target/classes
```

However, only the first bundle starts (adding line with \ separator doesn't work either).

This doesn't work too:

```
felix.auto.start.2 = \
 assembly:../test.bundle/target/classes
```

so I end up being able to start only one bundle. Not a very OSGi concept.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Following the [Felix documentation](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html#launcher-configuration-properties) `felix.auto.start.<n>` is a space-delimited list.

Answer (score 1):

add an extra space after \ separator write your config like this

```
felix.auto.deploy.action=install,start
felix.log.level=1

org.osgi.framework.storage.clean=onFirstInit

felix.auto.start.1 = \
 assembly:../test.bundle/target/classes \
 assembly:../test2.bundle/target/classes
```